# conditionally and efficiently changing specific values in column

Tags: r

This is my loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(df$column)){
  if((df$column[i] == '1') |(df$column[i] == '2') | (df$column[i] == '3')){
   df$column[i] = '1'}
  else{df$column[i] = '0'}
}
```

It's pretty simple. All that I'm doing is changing all values 1, 2 and 3 to 1, and the rest to 0 in a specific column. My dataset is extremely big though and this loop takes very long. Is there a better way to achieve the same result but faster?

Comment: wait i'm not even sure if my loop is achieving the desired outcome! Let me know if I'm wrong, but is my loop currently changing those values that have 1 to 0? the values that have 1 should stay as 1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All that I'm doing is changing all values 2 and 3 to 1, and the rest to 0 in a specific column.

This is as simple as

```
as.integer(df$column %in% 2:3)
```

Comment: wait i'm not even sure if my loop is achieving the desired outcome! Let me know if I'm wrong, but is my loop currently changing those values that have 1 to 0? the values that have 1 should stay as 1!

Comment: Yes.  Just include all those you want to be 1 on the right side.  So if you want 1, 2, 3, and 7 to be 1, then `column %in% c(1:3, 7)`

Comment: trying it out! will modify my post to make my loop correct

Comment: @jgozal - no need for a loop with this solution

Comment: Yeah @jgozal - No loop needed.  This is the entire answer.

Comment: yes yes i understand - i was just correcting the loop in the question because it wasnt accurately showing what i wanted to do. I added the `column == 1` condition in

Comment: this just took a few seconds compared to my loop that would take a few minutes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For a large data frame, you could use `data.table` for faster results:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, column := ifelse(column %in% 1:3, 1, 0)]
```

Comment: `ifelse` is not really needed, you could just wrap with `+`.  Anyway plus one.